# Apache sending Transfer-Encoding: chunked when deflate module is enabled

Tags: python, apache, wsgi

I have a simple web.py code like below, deployed with mod_wsgi in apache.

```py
import web

urls = (
    '/', 'index'
)

class index:
    def GET(self):
        content = 'hello'
        web.header('Content-length', len(content))
        return content

app = web.application(urls, globals())
application = app.wsgifunc()
```

This website runs well, except one minor issue. When mod_deflate is turn on, the response is chunked, even it has a very small response body.

Response Header

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 20 May 2015 20:14:12 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Encoding: gzip
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/html
```

[image: deflate is turn on]

When mod_deflate is **turn off**, `Content-Length` header is back.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 20 May 2015 20:30:09 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
Content-Length: 5
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
```

[image: deflate is turn off]

I've searched around and someone said reduce the [DeflateBufferSize](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_deflate.html#DeflateBufferSize) will help, but this response's size is only 5, far from it's default value: 8096, so I don't think it interferes with this issue.

And someone said apache send chunked response because it doesn't know the response's size before begin to send the response to client, but in my code, I do set Content-Length.

I've also tried [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org) and Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS), same result.

How do I set content-length when deflate module is enabled? and I don't like to gzip content in python.

Answer (score 1):

The response `Content-Length` has to reflect the final length of the data sent after the compression has been done, not the original length. Thus mod_deflate has to remove the original `Content-Length` header and use chunked transfer encoding. The only way it could otherwise know the content length to be able to send the `Content-Length` before sending the compressed data, would be to buffer up the complete compressed response in memory or into a file and then calculate the length. Buffering all the compressed content isn't practical and in part defeats the point of compressing the data as the response is streamed.

If you don't want mod_deflate enabled for the whole site, then only enable it for certain URL prefixes by scoping it within a `Location` block.